# How to add JAR files to VS code?

Tags: java, jar, visual-studio-code

I have the following `./lib` folder with JAR files which I would like to add to VS code referenced libraries.

[image: jar files]

VS code allows for glob pattern recognition but I'm not too familiar with glob.

Can someone explain how I add all the .jar pictured, the jar files were found by searching `.jar` at `/project/lin64/5.03.012_01/project5.03.012/task/lib/`.

The lib file structure looks like this:
[image: File structure]

The example for adding jars given by Vs Code is:

```
"java.project.referencedLibraries": {
    "include": [
        "library/**/*.jar",
        "/home/username/lib/foo.jar"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "library/sources/**"
    ],
    "sources": {
        "library/bar.jar": "library/sources/bar-src.jar"
    }
}
```

My attempt:

```
"java.project.referencedLibraries": {
        "include":[
            "/project/lin64/5.03.012_01/project5.03.012/task/lib/**/*.jar"
        ]
        
    }
```

I noticed in [their example](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-pack/raw/main/release-notes/v0.9.0/reference-jar-files.gif) they just click `+` icon on the `Referenced library` tab but I don't have this option after updating my settings.json

[image]

Comment: Basically, add jars to **Referenced Libraries** is for no build tools projects. Did you use maven or gradle in your current project? If not, please reinstall [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) then see if the option Referenced Libraries exists and you can [add a jar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_add-a-jar).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is what you mean. If not I am extremely sorry. You can find the folder where all of the code is stored, then just drag and drop the JAR files inside.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).